# Can you eat "congealed blood" meat?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, meat

I had read that when kosher meat slabs are delivered in a refrigerated truck, say, across the U.S., the meat must be hosed down every 2-3 days (I don't recall the exact time period) to prevent the blood from congealing.

Let's say this wasn't done. Is the meat considered "permanently" non-kosher and it cannot be used by Jews? Or can it still be made kosher in some way?

Are there different rules on this regarding meat vs. fowl / poultry? (perhaps, birds have a different time-frame for congealing than beef)?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to confirm that such hosings are actually performed and to just ask why before asking what happens if they aren't performed?

Comment: @DoubleAA Obviously, it would. I'm asking this question mainly in terms of understanding the halacha behind it. I'm not suggesting this as being practical. Of course, it's possible to have eaten the meat assuming that it was fine, until someone told you that it wasn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to remove the blood from meat (‘kashering’) through salting, the salting must be done within 72 hours of slaughter. Soaking the meat during that 72 hour period restarts the clock.

**If the meat is neither salted nor soaked within the time limit, it can no longer be ‘kashered’ by salting, but must instead be broiled to remove the blood, after which it may be eaten.**

Once it has been broiled, it should not be cooked, but if it is subsequently cooked it may be eaten ex post facto.

Source: [Shulchan Aruch Yoreh De’ah 69:12-13](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.69.12?lang=he)

And [here](http://rabbikaganoff.com/the-crisis-of-unwashed-meat/) is an informative (and entertaining) English article on the topic.